# WorksheetFunction in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with the following.  I want to use the match function to check (for each value in column A that isn't blank) if the value exists in column B and if it does I want it to post the value to sheet2 in the same cell destination. I'm getting an error once it reaches the line with "match" in it which is "object doesn´t support this property or method." Just in case the way I choose to code it is confusing the function I want it to do is `=match(cl.address; B; 0)`.  My code is

```
Sub UseFunction()
    Dim myRange As Range

    For Each cl In Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A:A")
        If cl.Value <> "" Then
            If cl.WorksheetFunction.Match(cl.Address, B, 0) Then
                Worksheets("sheet2").cl.Value = Worksheets("sheet1").cl.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Const SOURCE_SHEET = "sheet1"
Private Const TARGET_SHEET = "sheet2"

Sub test()
    Dim cl As Range, matchResult As Double
    Dim source As Worksheet
    Dim target As Worksheet

    Set source = Worksheets(SOURCE_SHEET)
    Set target = Worksheets(TARGET_SHEET)

    On Error Resume Next

    With source
        For Each cl In .UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
            If cl.Value <> "" Then
                matchResult = 0
                matchResult = WorksheetFunction.Match(cl.Value, .UsedRange.Columns("B"), 0)
                If (matchResult > 0) Then target.Cells(cl.Row, cl.Column).Value = cl.Value
            End If
        Next cl
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`=match(cl.address; B; 0)` is not a valid formula. If you meant to say "column B", that'd be `B:B`.

`cl.WorksheetFunction.Match` should be `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`.

For the second parameter you want `Worksheets("sheet1").Columns(2)` or `Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B:B")`.

`Match(cl.address, ...)` will try to find the address of `cl` in column B stored as string, not the value of `cl`. If you want to find the value, use `Match(cl.value, ...)`